# Failed to export PATH on mac

Tags: macos

I added my python bin folder to environment variable `PATH`,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

But failed with the following statement

```
set: Warning: path component /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory...
```

What happened? I just do as many other do(Google Search). The shell used is fish.

Comment: OS X already has Python installed, so why do you need to edit the path to include it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using bash (or ksh) syntax which doesn't work in fish.

The fish docs cover setting the PATH here: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path

The syntax you want is:

```
set PATH $PATH /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with my Macbook Pro, it working fine by edit file `~/.bash_profile`. You can see example below:
But this work for me only temporary, after  close terminal I need to run 
`source ~/.bash_profile` again

```
set JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
set MAVEN_HOME /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
set XAMP_HOME /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
set ANDROID_HOME /Users/sochy/Documents/sdk
set ZIPALIGN /Users/sochy/Documents/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2
set GOPATH $HOME/go
set PORT /opt/local/bin
set PATH $PATH $JAVA_HOME $MAVEN_HOME $XAMP_HOME $ANDROID_HOME $ZIPALIGN $GOPATH $PORT $HOME/flutter/bin
```

Another solution I try below for permanently configure by edit file source `~/.bash_profile` and then restart terminal

```
export JAVA_HOME=Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
export MAVEN_HOME=opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
export XAMP_HOME=Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=Users/sochy/Documents/sdk
export ZIPALIGN=Users/sochy/Documents/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PORT=opt/local/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME:$MAVEN_HOME:$XAMP_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME:$ZIPALIGN:$GOPATH:$PORT:$HOME/flutter/bin
```